# Why no compile error for `std::reference_wrapper<void>` in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, std, c++-concepts

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
requires (!std::is_void_v<T>)
struct A {};

int main()
{    
    A<void>*                      p1{}; // compile error as expected.
    std::reference_wrapper<void>* p2{}; // no expected compile error!    
}
```

Now since C++20 has `concepts` to restrict the class template parameters, and `void` is not valid for `std::reference_wrapper`:

**Why no compile error for** `std::reference_wrapper<void>` **in C++20?**

Comment: "void is not valid for std::reference_wrapper" I don't find this in the standard. The constraints are applied to the constructor, not to the type itself.

Comment: Why doesn't the C++20 standard explicitly require that `void` is not valid for `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: If guess because reference wrappers for blood don't do any real harm and allow for easier templated code that has to deal with functions that may or may not have return types

Comment: I think it's because void pointers are the only ones that you can do pointer-to-objects with. It's not possible with any other type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no one has written  the concept `requires (!std::is_void_v<T>)` for `std::reference_wrapper`. I agree, `void` should not be valid for `std::reference_wrapper`, and allowing `void` is probably an oversight from the standard.

You would think that `std::reference_wrapper<void>` wouldn't compile anyway, as `void&` isn't legal. But `std::reference_wrapper` uses *pointers* under the covers instead of references, and `void*` is a perfectly legal pointer, which is why `std::reference_wrapper<void>` compiles.